# Search for file csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
count = 0
with open('Test.csv',  encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
    for line in file:
       if "K,K,K,K" in line:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

```
The output:11

Im looking to get the whole line out

Example into the file

06/03/2021,3,K,K,K,K

12/04/2021,29,9,A,8,9

16/03/2019,7,Q,8,9,8

26/02/2020,50,K,K,K,K
```

Comment: Please share more clear information about your issue to get better notifications. If you are new to Stackoverflow, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: define your question properly

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the line, then instead of `count+=1`, add `print(line)`.

Comment: Perfect ,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This starts with an empty list and then any matches are stored in the list as they are found, then you can re-use the list any time in the rest of your code.

```
count = 0
k_matches=[]
with open('Test.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if "K,K,K,K" in line:
            k_matches.append(line)
            count+=1

print(k_matches)
```

Output of print

```
['06/03/2021,3,K,K,K,K', '26/02/2020,50,K,K,K,K']
```